# MVC - Partial View for Layout loads, but does not trigger javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

My shared page layout,`_CustomerLayout.cshtml` has:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
 </div>
```

The `_LoginPartial.cshtml` has:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hello, " + User.Identity.Name + "!", "UserProfile", "Home")</li>
        <li>
            <a href="~/ShoppingCart/Index" id="ShoppingCartSpace"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" id="ShoppingCartIcon"></i></a>
            <span class="badge" id="BadgeIcon"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The BadgeIcon is what I want to display in every View, so I made a script that would take the current user's shopping cart from database, calculate the total cart quantity on the fly, and then .ajax the return in the `#BadgeIcon` div

The script located at the end of `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is:

```
@section scripts
{
<script>     //never gets triggered

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("getCartCount", "ShoppingCart")',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#BadgeIcon').html(data);
            }
        })
    });

</script>
}
```

Also posting this snippet from the ShoppingCartController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getCartCount()
    {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            var cartCount = user.ShoppingCarts.FirstOrDefault().ShoppingCartProducts.Sum(x => x.Quantity);

            return Json(cartCount);
    }
```

As you may tell, I am far from an expert on MVC, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any script errors in the debug console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the answer which was found by Pravin Tukadiya and Jasen:

Added

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

to `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and removed

```
@section scripts{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

partial view has no layout so section will not work.
so,try to remove section element and write code of javascript directly  in partial view.

```
@section scripts //remove this
{
}
```

Comment: Didn't mention this when I asked the question,but I have already tried this to no avail

Comment: did you check console of browser ?

Comment: what will be return if shopping cart is empty ? I think your error is in your code side..

Comment: user.ShoppingCarts.FirstOrDefault()==null?0:user.ShoppingCarts.FirstOrDefault().ShoppingCartProducts.Sum(x => x.Quantity); write like this..

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have changed it the way you asked, and it still doesn't hit. I put a breakpoint on the actual ActionResult on my controller and it never reaches the breakpoint. Looking at console, one thing it says is "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: `$ is not defined` means _jquery.js_ was not loaded before your partial view script executed.

Comment: where you render your _CustomerLayout.cshtml partial view ?